# Problem accessing Ubuntu Host Serial Port in VirtualBox Winxp Guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, serial-port, virtualbox

I am having a difficult time trying to access a serial port on VirtualBox.
My Guest OS is Windows XP and the host environment is Linux Ubuntu 10.04.

The serial modem device works perfectly in Ubuntu. I can communicate with it
via cutecom or just sending plain echo messages to it like so:

> echo "id"  >  /dev/ttyS2

**Ubuntu Settings and config**

I have added my user account to the following group: **dialout**
and have set the serial using the following command: `sudo setserial /dev/ttyS2`
but still no luck when trying to access it in my Guest OS.

**Heres the settings I use to configure the serial port in VirtualBox:**

- Port Mode      : Host Device
- Port Number    : User - Defined (IRQ = 17, I/O Port = 0xEC00)
- Port/File Path : /dev/ttyS2

I have tried all the different port modes even disconnected but still no luck.
I have consulted the manual aswell but nothing works.
What could be wrong? Is it virtualbox or are my ubuntu settings configured incorrectly?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You can ask on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip Vlad. P
I posted my question on askubuntu and got a very prompt and detailed response.
Heres the link : https://askubuntu.com/questions/16586/how-to-access-serial-ubuntu-host-serial-port-on-virtualbox-guest-os